# Welcome aboard flight 5932

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

Welcome aboard flight 5932, and thanks for getting on this flight.

In the unlikely case you need or want to abort this flight, you will find there are two exits both at the top of the plane.

This flight will hopefully to take you to where you want to go

If this flight was to crash we advise calling for help. There are specialists which could help fix the crash.

We hope that you enjoy this flight

> Help me make sense of this

Comment: This question does not make sense to someone who is not viewing it within a stipulated time-frame.

Comment: @Abhijit actually it does. If you click on newest and count backwards from the number of questions you'll end up on 5933 when you reach this question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Welcome to the flight 5932, and thanks for getting on this flight.

> This is question number 5932 on Puzzling StackExchange! [image: Question number 5932]

In the unlikely case you need or want to abort this flight, you will find there are two exits both at the top of the plane.

> If you do not wish to view this question, you can click on the Puzzling icon or the questions link on the top to view other questions.

This flight will hopefully to take you to where you want to go

> This puzzle might be good enough to thrill you and satisfy your urge for puzzles.

If this flight was to crash we advise calling for help. There are specialists which could help fix the crash.

> If this question happens to be not of good quality, we can flag moderators for their attention and possible intervention.

We hope that you enjoy this flight

> The poster hopes that puzzlers enjoy this question.

Comment: How did you find/confirm about the question number?

Comment: @manshu: Edited in the reasoning for the number.

Comment: Well done! This was just a fun one

Comment: @manshu Clarification: There are 5932 questions here, and CodeNewbie watches the "newest" tab, with this question on top (*the* newest). So this is #5932, the first being #1.